# Readynas python 'version' reference

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm trying to run Headphones on my Readynas duo with Python 2.6 but am experiencing an error relating to determining the OS version. As a non-python expert I wonder if anyone can help me out with the following stack trace:

```
[   couchpotato.core.event] Error in event "app.version", that wasn't caught: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/share/cpserver/couchpotato/core/event.py", line 12, in runHandler
    return handler(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/cpserver/couchpotato/core/_base/_core/main.py", line 167, in version
    elif 'Darwin' in platform.platform(): platf = 'osx'   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/platform.py", line 1520, in platform
    elif system in ('Linux',):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/platform.py", line 361, in dist
    return linux_distribution(distname, version, id,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/platform.py", line 333, in linux_distribution
    firstline = f.readline()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/platform.py", line 269, in
_parse_release_file
    else: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment encoding=UTF-8 debug=False args=['--daemon', '--data_dir', '/media/UsenetTmp/.couchpotato', '--pid_file=/var/run/cpserver/server.pid'] app_dir=/usr/share/cpserver data_dir=/media/UsenetTmp/.couchpotato desktop=None options=Namespace(config_file='/media/UsenetTmp/.couchpotato/settings.conf', console_log=False, daemon=True, data_dir='/media/UsenetTmp/.couchpotato', debug=False, pid_file='/var/run/cpserver/server.pid', quiet=False)
```

Comment: Can you post the related code?

Answer (score 0):

That's a python2.6 bug (can't find an issue number atm, but it's fixed in 2.7). The code checking for detailed OS version information on a Linux system was coded in this way:

```
def _parse_release_file(firstline):
    #some code
    l = string.split(string.strip(firstline))
    if l:
        version = l[0]
    #more code
    return '', version, id
```

Thus, if the release file is empty, the `version` variable is never assigned to, which throws the `UnboundLocalError` on trying to return it.

To fix this, you could patch the `platform.py` file to not throw this error, preferably by adding the lines `version = ''` and `id = ''` at the beginning of `_parse_release_file` - this is how it's fixed in 2.7. If you can't modify that file on your NAS, try modifying the couchpotato sources and replace the call to `platform.platform()`with a hardcoded string like `"Linux-generic-x86"`.